# default page needs to be changed to notebooks instead home page in Hue

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue

In hue I want the following notebooks page to be appeared by default instead home page when the user logs in. How can I make this page?[image: This should appear first after login].

http://localhost:8888/notebook/notebooks

Answer (score 0):

You can use rewriteHandler for jetty server, hue uses it https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Rewrite_Handler

Comment: could you please tell me the changes that I need to make and their  relevant files in Hue?

Comment: I see on signIn,  the form submit is happening and the action that is being called is accounts/login. ( <form method="POST" action="/accounts/login/" autocomplete="off">), In which file I can find the function that is handling this action="/accounts/login/", so that there after ajax response I will try to redirect to /notebook/notebooks ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to comment [these 5 lines](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/desktop/core/src/desktop/urls.py#L64) and put something like:

```
dynamic_patterns += patterns('notebook.views',
  (r'^home$','notebook'),
)
```